# DetectChanges: No entry for relationships if key property present

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two classes with an parent-child (1:n) relationship and want to detect when the parent has been changed by adding a child to it.

I have overriden the `SaveChanges` method of the context:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var ctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;

    ctx.DetectChanges();
    var entries = ctx.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted | EntityState.Modified);
    foreach (var entry in entries)
    {
        if (entry.IsRelationship)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Relationship");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Entity");
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

As expected, when adding a child to the parent I get an entity entry for the child and a relationship entry for the parent-child relationship. But as soon as the child class contains a key property for the parent, I no longer get any relationship entries for this relationship.

```
class Class1
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Class2> Class2s { get; set; }
}

class Class2
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] public int Id { get; set; }
    public Class1 Parent { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; } // <-- no relationship entries if present
}
```

Is this expected behavior? How can I detect relationship changes when the id column is present?

Comment: You are using Fluent and ModelBuilder to tell EF that ParentId is actually the Foreign key?  I don't see a DataAnnotation and you included no modelbuilder code.

Comment: No, EF automatically assumes that `ParentId` is the foreign key due to the [convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679962(v=vs.113).aspx#Relationship%20Convention).

Comment: True.  "name that follows one of the following formats represents a foreign key for the relationship: '<navigation property name><principal primary key property name>', '<principal class name><primary key property name>', or '<principal primary key property name>'"  But do you really want to count on that not changing?  Core is a whole 'nuther animal.  Better to be explicit than try to figure out "what happened"

Comment: I don't need to figure out "what happened" because the convention tells it. And I'm not trying to migrate to EF Core. I'm trying to detect relationship changes here. It doesn't change anything about the problem if I configure the foreign key explicitly using Fluent API or DataAnnotation.